# Can an iPhone app developed with Phonegap and Meteor JS be successfully deployed to the App Store?

Tags: cordova, meteor

I'm wondering whether someone has come across this already: I'm trying to develop my first iPhone app using Phonegap and Meteor JS. I'm able to compile and deploy to my iPhone and all that. But will Apple reject my app?

Meteor allows to update code LIVE, so once deployed to the app store, I could potentially update the code after the app's been deployed without having to go through the app approval process again.

Is that a fair statement? If that's the case should I really be using Meteor at all in my iPhone application?

Comment: Not sure why it's been closed as off topic, but the answer is yes, it can be done, in fact http://www.gander.io/ had good success with it (not sure if they are using phonegap, but they are defo using Meteor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The company I work for publishes applications that rely heavily on our HTML/JS platform and can be upgraded dynamically, and we do not constantly need to publish every time the HTML updates.  However, you will need to re-publish if you change some of the material that hooks into the native code.

Comment: (I'll double check with the guy who explained to me and make sure this is a precise explanation of what has to be republished on change; but given that this is our business model I am pretty sure about the general idea!)

Comment: yep, you can do this, we do it, etc.

Comment: thanks airza, that helps a lot!